# how to hide selected items in suggestion list in ui.bootstrap.typeahead angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I add each selected items in suggestion list in [ui.bootstrap.typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) in `ng-click` angularjs event to another list to show to users(these users are selected), Now I want don't suggest these selected items in suggestion list.

what can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the source to not selected items from where you read typeahead data and on select assign selected item f.e: item.selected = true and on remove the selected item assign false.